# Is there a command to set the default path in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, path, default

`hg clone` sets up the default path, so that you can pull and push without specifying the url every time.

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/account/repository
```

But if you have an existing local repository and decide to share it on bitbucket, you won't get the default path setup for you.

```
hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/account/repository
```

Is there a command to set the default path or am I forced to manually edit .hg/hgrc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There isn't a command for this and there won't be one.  One of the times this was suggested the primary author of Mercurial, Matt, [tweeted:](http://twitter.com/#!/mpmselenic/status/8392230762)

> What is it with coders who are intimidated by text-based config files? Like doctors that can't stand blood.

You can make the `hg erc` command open up that editor by putting this in your personal `.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
erc = !$EDITOR `$HG root`/.hg/hgrc
```

(that last from Steve Losh)

If you want to get fancy you could do a `post-clone` hook that modifies the `.hg\hgrc` file using sed or similar, but you'll not find that functionality in Mercurial any time soon.

Comment: It's not that I'm intimidated by text-based config files. It's just much faster to execute a command than editing a text file. What's wrong with saving time and simplify stuff?

Comment: The thinking is that a program can never edit a human-edited config file in a 100% safe way.  Naive substitutions break in odd cases (what if there are two default= lines (illegal) or two [paths] sections (legal)) and full load/parse/modify/render/save cycles break on incorrectly formed input files and can loose human-only markup like whitespace amounts and comments.  Or what if my .hg/hgrc uses %include to include a snippet from elsewhere?  Does the editor have to follow that and try to go edit that file?  It's just one of those things that's harder than its value.

Comment: A doctor should prevent bleeding, if possible.

Comment: Btw, the section name is `[alias]`, not `[aliases]`.

Comment: @Ry4an I don't buy it. Because Tortoisehg GIVES that feature.. which means it parses, reads and sets it. One explanation for both true is Tortoise fails that, does it? I don't use it but believes it works. :P

Comment: I definitely use `.hgrc` files that TortoiseHG would corrupt if it tried to save them out.  TortoiseHG is great, but it's not a part of the Mercurial project.

Comment: The internet treats censorship of features as failure and forks around it.

Comment: @Barry and there are plenty of extensions that add it -- and it usually works but sometimes breaks your config exactly like git's equivalent command.  No amount of wishing makes parsing and emitting a config file deterministic if the format wasn't designed for it -- and neither Mercurial's nor git's were.

Comment: @Ry4an: Thanks for following up.  I haven't looked at it lately; what are some of the harder edge cases for a smarter lexer that are interesting beyond preserving/respecting comments in-place, handling %include/%unset?  Multiline indent aint a context-free grammar, that's for sure.   Another point might be 'delete a key' behavior could use a comment to be least entropic, but the behavior needs to be explicit as to 'delete' all from all sections or just last, and add an %unset or not.  Config files are so small / importance, they should be backed up verbosely as this comment. :)

Comment: The environment variable interpolation of the config files makes it tricky too.  The %include could be one file this time and another that time.

Comment: Just another example of a non-issue on git that is broken in hg because the author can't envision a day when "640 kB isn't enough" for everyone.

Answer (score 6):

If you're running TortoiseHg, you can also bring up the Repository Explorer and select Synchronize->Configure Paths... this will allow you to define the default path, and any additional paths you may want. For example, you could configure a path with the alias 'bitbucket' and use your default path for a local clone, server copy, etc...

Changes made in this fashion are not stored in the .hgrc or Mercurial.ini file because they are per repo - they are instead stored in the .hg directory.

Comment: +1 for simple way (if using Tortoise). Which actually does what the selected answer (Ry4an's) does under the hood.

Comment: How do I bring up the Repository Explorer?

Comment: @FelixDombek I assume this has changed between versions. In 4.9, you can hit Alt+4 (or View, Synchronize) and you'll see the "Paths in Repository Settings" windows and you can right click "edit" on each of the Aliases

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no builtin command; you need to add it in .hg/hgrc yourself.

Comment: I think there should be a command for this. Where can I file my bug report?

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/ although it's probably a fairly uncommon rcfile edit and I'd think it would be unlikely to be assigned a command.